# "invalid stream header: 00000000" error on flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm finishing my Flutter project but i realized that i cant run the app on my device. I have tried many devices and they didnt worked, but on the emulator the app runs without problems.
I have searched for this error but i didnt find any solution.

The error is:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > invalid stream header: 00000000

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to
get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
```

Comment: Did you try this advice at all? `Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to [...]`

Comment: I have tried but i cant, the command isnt recognized: flutter run --stacktrace
Could not find an option named "stacktrace".


Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter <command> -h') for available flutter commands and options.

Comment: Those seem to be options of `gradle`, not `flutter`

Comment: I dont know how to use it.

Comment: In VS Code go to the TERMINAL windows on the bottom pane. Then

cd android. Then

./gradlew build --scan (or --stacktrace)